# How to get value of second maximum salary of each employees in SQL and LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq

```
I have below SalaryTable.


----------------
EmpId   Salary  
----------------
1       100     
2       200     
3       300
1       400
2       500
3       600
1       700
2       800
3       900
1       1000
2       1100
3       1200
----------------
```

Sample Output

```
-------------------
EmpId       Salary
-------------------
1            700  
2            800 
3            900
-------------------
```

Eg:

```
All the salary of Employee ID 1 [100,400,700,1000] and 700 is second largest salary of employee 1
```

Like wise display all the employees. 
    I want to display each employee of second maximum salary in SQL And LINQ Query.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: your output will be the couple (2,800)?

Comment: a sample output would be helpful

Comment: Or you looking for an SQL solution or for a linq solution?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Ya sure @JoeTaras

Comment: @gab I have added sample Output and Scenario. You can checkt it now.

Comment: @Parameswaran added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL version:

```
SELECT EmpId, MAX(Salary) AS Salary
FROM SalaryTable x
WHERE Salary < (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM SalaryTable WHERE EmpId = x.EmpId)
GROUP BY EmpId
```

LINQ version:

```
list
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
   .Select(g => 
              g.GroupBy(item => item.Salary)
              .OrderByDescending(e => e.Key)
              .Skip(1)
              .First().First());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for details in Linq

```
var results = Context.Employees
             .GroupBy(b => b.Id)
             .Select(e => new Table1
             {
                 Id = e.Key,
                 Salary = e.OrderByDescending(f => f.Salary).Select(f => f.Salary).Distinct().Skip(1).First()
             }).ToList();
```

if its not sql friendly, execute ToList() after GroupBy

i added distinct in the salary part to check if employee Id = 1 has 450, 450, 450 and 300 as a salary, then 300 would be the 2nd highest salary in my mind